# Mercurial: Windows script to add subrepository automatically

Tags: powershell, mercurial, batch-file, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

[RyanWilcox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224334/ryanwilcox) had posted a script at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408772/how-do-i-add-a-subrepo-to-an-existing-repository-in-mercurial/2409375#2409375), that can use the following command to add subrepository automatically:

```
$ cd $TOP_OF_HG_PROJECT
$ addsubrepo.sh $URL_TO_HG_PROJECT relative_path/you/want_to/put_the_subrepo
```

How to translate it into Windows batch or powershell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty translation. Haven't tested as I got no Mercury around. The initial script seems to be easy enough to translate into Powershell.

```
# Project and relative paths as script parameters
param([string]$project, [string]$relPath)

# Let's see if there is an item .hg. If not, report error and quit
if((test-path ".hg") -eq $false ) {
   "You MUST run this at the top of your directory structure and use relative paths"
    return
}

# Call Mercury
& hg clone $project $relPath

# Add data to .hgsub using composite formatting string
add-content -path ".hgsub" -value $("{0} = {1}" -f $relPath, $project)

# Check that .hgsub exists and issue Mercury commands if it does
if(test-path ".hgsub") {
    hg add .hgsub
    hg commit
} else {
    "failure, see error messages above"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I get an error though. I need to replace `if(test-path ".hg" -eq $false )` to `if((test-path ".hg") -eq $false )`.