# How to create subrepository using Kallithea mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, kallithea

How to create subrepository using Kallithea mercurial
through the web interface of Kallithea ?

I have googled for it and didn't hit any results,

also I found this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944514/mercurial-windows-script-to-add-subrepository-automatically) which makes it through windows.

Or any alternative for Kallithea that can do this job easy.

Comment: Please note that the [mercurial documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository) explicitly warns **against** using this feature, and calls it a ["feature of last resort"](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FeaturesOfLastResort#But_I_need_to_have_managed_subprojects.21). Please make sure that you read and understand the documentation! At any rate, did you try [following the steps in the documentation](http://docs.kallithea-scm.org/en/latest/usage/vcs_support.html?highlight=subrepo#mercurial-support)?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker my goal is to find a method through Kallithea web interface, in the end I used commands as you mentioned , it's also the first time I read this note, thanks I will try to find an alternative